# Yii2 unlink records via junction table

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have two models; User and Raffle. I also have a junction table with just an `id`, a `user_id`, and a `raffle_id`.

I then get the Raffles from the User model like this:

```
public function getRaffles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Raffle::class, ['id' => 'raffle_id'])
        ->viaTable('raffle_user', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

And from the Raffles model like this:

```
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, ['id' => 'user_id'])
        ->viaTable('raffle_user', ['raffle_id' => 'id']);
}
```

This works, and I can successfully call `$user->link('raffles', $raffle);` etc.

However, when I try to unlink a record like `$user->unlink('raffles', $raffle);` I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'raffle_id' cannot be null
```

Am I doing something wrong, or do I have something misconfigured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record says following

> By default, the unlink() method will set the foreign key value(s) that
> specify the existing relationship to be null. You may, however, choose
> to delete the table row that contains the foreign key value by passing
> the $delete parameter as true to the method.

So don't you have your column `raffle_id` defined as NOT NULL ? It would explain the situation.

You should pass `true` as third attribute or set off the `NOT NULL` settings on the column.

Btw, it should use the same relation. Why do you have there `raffles` when `link` and `raffle` when `unlink`?

Comment: The raffles/raffle was a typo. They're both raffles. As for unlink, does passing true not also delete the foreign object? So `$user->unlink('raffles', $raffle, true);` would delete the raffle? that's what the documentation sounds like

Comment: As far as I read the documentation - setting the third attribute to `true` should delete the row in the join table (raffle_user - many to many). Did you try it? How does it behave?